# Please Help me where to put payable and fallback in my source

Tags: go-ethereum, metamask, myetherwallet, ico

This problem shows with a message

[image: ERROR]

I know there's problem with source
There's no payable, fallback source in it.

1. Please tell me about payable & fallback source and where to put it.

Or

This source is from ethereum.org/token

```
function buy() payable returns (uint amount){
    amount = msg.value / buyPrice;                    // calculates the amount
    require(balanceOf[this] >= amount);               // checks if it has enough to sell
    balanceOf[msg.sender] += amount;                  // adds the amount to buyer's balance
    balanceOf[this] -= amount;                        // subtracts amount from seller's balance
    Transfer(this, msg.sender, amount);               // execute an event reflecting the change
    return amount;                                    // ends function and returns
}

function sell(uint amount) returns (uint revenue){
    require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= amount);         // checks if the sender has enough to sell
    balanceOf[this] += amount;                        // adds the amount to owner's balance
    balanceOf[msg.sender] -= amount;                  // subtracts the amount from seller's balance
    revenue = amount * sellPrice;
    msg.sender.transfer(revenue);                     // sends ether to the seller: it's important to do this last to prevent recursion attacks
    Transfer(msg.sender, this, amount);               // executes an event reflecting on the change
    return revenue;                                   // ends function and returns
}
```

2. where can i put in my source and which elements in the source has to be changed? Also function sell could work except for fallback sign?

Down here is my main source.
I worked this over 40hours without sleeping

### Please, I want to solve this struggles.

```
pragma solidity 0.4.19;

contract Token {


    function totalSupply() constant returns (uint supply) {}


    function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint balance) {}


    function transfer(address _to, uint _value) returns (bool success) {}


    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint _value) returns (bool success) {}


    function approve(address _spender, uint _value) returns (bool success) {}


    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) constant returns (uint remaining) {}

    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint _value);
    event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint _value);
}

contract RegularToken is Token {

    function transfer(address _to, uint _value) returns (bool) {

        if (balances[msg.sender] >= _value && balances[_to] + _value >= balances[_to]) {
            balances[msg.sender] -= _value;
            balances[_to] += _value;
            Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
            return true;
        } else { return false; }
    }

    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint _value) returns (bool) {
        if (balances[_from] >= _value && allowed[_from][msg.sender] >= _value && balances[_to] + _value >= balances[_to]) {
            balances[_to] += _value;
            balances[_from] -= _value;
            allowed[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
            Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
            return true;
        } else { return false; }
    }

    function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint) {
        return balances[_owner];
    }

    function approve(address _spender, uint _value) returns (bool) {
        allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) constant returns (uint) {
        return allowed[_owner][_spender];
    }

    mapping (address => uint) balances;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint)) allowed;
    uint public totalSupply;
}

contract UnboundedRegularToken is RegularToken {

    uint constant MAX_UINT = 2**256 - 1;


    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint _value)
        public
        returns (bool)
    {
        uint allowance = allowed[_from][msg.sender];
        if (balances[_from] >= _value
            && allowance >= _value
            && balances[_to] + _value >= balances[_to]
        ) {
            balances[_to] += _value;
            balances[_from] -= _value;
            if (allowance < MAX_UINT) {
                allowed[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
            }
            Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

contract ParentToken is UnboundedRegularToken {

    uint public totalSupply = 20*10**26;
    uint8 constant public decimals = 18;
    string constant public name = "ParentToken";
    string constant public symbol = "PAT";

    function ParentToken() {
        balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply;
        Transfer(address(0), msg.sender, totalSupply);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Please tell me about payable & fallback source and where to put it.

**Fallback** are triggered when the function signature does not match any of the available functions in a Solidity contract (like when you send ETH without specifically calling any function).

**Payable** is a modifier that allows a contract to accept ethers. You can make a function payable and then ethers can be sent to contract while calling this function. The `wei` value is present in `msg.value` param.

> where can i put in my source and which elements in the source has to be changed? Also function sell could work except for fallback sign?

Since you have marked `buy` as payable function. this means you can call `buy` with paying some ETH to contract.

But if you send ETH directly without calling any function. It won't do much. If you want that someone pays ETH and `buy` function is invoked. You can call `buy` function from the `fallback` function. The fallback function has no method name.

```
function ()  payable{
    buy();
}
```

Be careful with this as this will allow you contract to accept ETH and there must be a source to withdraw ETH from the contract.

Comment: how can i use this function and where to put it?
I would like to set up 1 eth = 10000 (symbol), 0.01 eth = 1000, 0.001 eth = 100 like this. however i have no idea please im beggin you.. help me out function () payable {buy (); }